# Presence of 555 square wave generator breaks the rest of the circuit even when not connected.

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, multisim

I have a pretty bizarre problem with Multisim. I have a larger circuit which works perfectly when the inbuilt square wave generator for Multsim is used. I wish to replace the square wave generator with my own.

I have a 555 square generator circuit which works perfectly when I test it by itself, the moment I recreate that circuit in the main circuit and connect it to a 5V source the output of the main circuit just stops after a few milliseconds. This only occurs when the square wave generator is connected to a source without even connecting it to the rest of the circuit, when I remove the 5V source the circuit simulates for a few seconds and then just stops the only way to get the correct waveform is to completely[![enter image description here][1]][1] remove the 555 square wave circuit.

When I do connect the 555 timer I get an incorrect output for a few milliseconds and the circuit stops anyway. I have no idea why the presence of the timer breaks the rest of the circuit and I was hoping someone could enlighten me on this.[image]
[image: output when the 555 timer is disconnected from the circuit but the 5V source to it is connected]

[image: output when it is connected]

The circuit is supposed to count up until the green wave form reaches the red and then it resets and starts again.

Answer (score 3):

You have used earth for the 555 instead of circuit ground.

[image]

*Figure 1. There is no ground return path for the 555 oscillator.*

Replace the earth symbol with a ground symbol.

Oh, and please turn off the grid for screengrabs!

Comment: Thank you, however it is still not working. I have narrowed the problem down to the 555 timer not playing nice with the staircase circuit but I am still baffled as to why. I can post a link of just those two components if you would like to play around with them yourself?

Comment: I don't have MultiSim. Sorry. I'm not sure what's supposed to happen at the right side of C1. Are you missing a pull-up or -down resistor?